# UWP Store App with AAD B2C using Blazor Web/Api

Tags: uwp, azure-ad-b2c, blazor, windows-store

I am developing an UWP app that I would like to submit into the Microsoft Store.
For user management I plan to use the Azure AD B2C (replacing the existing ASP.Net Identity framework) and for web related (Web pages and APIs) development I am using the Blazor Server Side framework.

I have some experience in every used frameworks but to put everything together is a bit shady.
My questions are:

1. How to connect the AAD B2C with my own database? I mean to store user relating data at least the userIDs have to be stored to maintain relationships (regardless I choose an SQL on NoSQL approach). What is a good practice to synchronize the AAD B2C with my DB? Creating a User table only containing the available UserIds is fine and updating it after every new user registration? I wouldn't like to keep any other sensitive data in my DB.
2. How to manage the Microsoft Store's account? I mean when I user downloads the application it should automatically register an account into the AAD B2C as a Microsoft Account under the hood and log in the user with the given account? As I understand the Store Apps are tied to one MS account so implementing login/logout options are not necessary because the user is identified automatically with the local windows user account, right?
3. Can I collect and reuse the MS Store subscription details in the future? For example I decide to create a Web App version of the App, then the same user can use his existing subscription for the Web App version? Because the user is already paid for the app and the user can be identified technically. Or I have to use a different subscription/licencing system for that.

I appreciate your answers! :)